# JQuery validator custom error placement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate

I created a checkbox using custom images and with the great help of @TrueBlueAussie. I am now stuck on the next step which is placing a validation error message after the custom checkbox.

If I unhide the checkbox I can see that it is being checked / not checked. I also get the validation error appears as expected. Although this works, unchecking checkbox via the image button does not remove the error messgae.

Furthermore, when I add back `display:none` to the checkbox, the error message does not show at all. What is wrong with my code?

I have created a [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/5y213o6c/) to show the issue. Please remove `display:none` from the checkbox to see the symptoms.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="AcceptTerms_check" name="AcceptTerms_check" style="display:none;"> 
<img class="chk-img" id="AcceptTerms" src="../../../wp-content/uploads/misc/notselected.png">
<span id="ts-cs-accept">I have read and accept the Terms and Conditions.</span>
```

jQuery validator code:

```
 jQuery("#InstallerForm").validate({
     rules: {
         InstBizNam: {
             required: true
         },
         AcceptTerms_check: {
             required: true
         }
     },
     messages: {
         InstBizNam: "Please enter business name",
         AcceptTerms_check: "Please read and accept the program terms to submit your application"
     },
     errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
         if (element.attr("name") == "AcceptTerms_check") {
             error.insertAfter("#ts-cs-accept");
         } else {
             error.insertAfter(element);
         }
     },
     submitHandler: function (form) {
         alert("SUBMITTED!");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because by default the hidden elements are excluded from the validation. You can pass a custom selector to the `ignore` option to override the default settings.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#InstallerForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  jQuery('.chk-img').click(function(e) {
    var element = jQuery(this);
    var $checkbox = jQuery('input:checkbox[name=' + this.id + '_check]');
    if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
      $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
      jQuery(element).attr("src", "//placehold.it/24/ff0000");
    } else {
      $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
      jQuery(element).attr("src", "//placehold.it/24/00ff00");
    }
    $checkbox.valid()
  });

  jQuery("#InstallerForm").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden:not(#AcceptTerms_check)',
    rules: {
      InstBizNam: {
        required: true
      },
      AcceptTerms_check: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      InstBizNam: "Please enter business name",
      AcceptTerms_check: "<br/>Please read and accept the program terms to submit your application"
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr("name") == "AcceptTerms_check") {
        error.insertAfter("#ts-cs-accept");
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert("SUBMITTED!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="InstallerForm" name="InstallerForm" action="" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="InstBizNam">Business Name*:</label>
    <input name="InstBizNam" id="InstBizNam" type="text" class="input-text" tabindex="5" placeholder="Business Name" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="AcceptTerms_check" name="AcceptTerms_check" style="display:none;" />
    <img class="chk-img" id="AcceptTerms" src="//placehold.it/24/ff0000" /> <span id="ts-cs-accept">Accept Terms</span>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Application" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

In the above case we are ignoring all hidden elements other than the `#AcceptTerms_check` one.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the reply. So it cannot be done via jQuery validator? At least not with my approach?

Comment: @TheRealPapa see the demo... it can be fixed

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the reply!!! AWESOME! Only thing is once the error appears via validation, checking the image (hidden checkbox) does not remove the error. It is as if validator does not catch the "checked" event of the hidden checkbox. Is there a simple way around this?

Comment: Hi @Arun P Johny, yes I beat you with my reply to you finishing the demo. AWESOME! Can the last piece be also incorporated so validator removes the error on the user checking the "image"?

Comment: Hi @Arun P Johny, you ROCK! I would not have worked this out without your help!!!

Comment: Hi  @Arun P Johny, I have to say THANKS AGAIN! I learned a lot from your example!